# how to add dictionary to PyEnchant on windows

Tags: python, deep-learning, pyenchant, enchant

I'm using PyEnchant  for the first time, I want to check if a word is in french or not

```
import enchant
d = enchant.Dict('fr_FR')
d.check("Hello") # False
```

but I'm having this error *DictNotFoundError*
so I have to add fr_FR to the list of languages I found this command
`sudo apt-get install myspell-fr-fr`

but this is for Linux what is the equivalent command for windows?

(sorry 4 my eng)